# when springboot running, it has a debug info

Tags: spring-boot, maven

#### Problem description

> In the process of setting up the environment, I saw a debug level log message in the log, I think there is something wrong here, so I would like to ask the teacher to help analyze what is the problem? I couldn't find a solution on StackOverflow either.

#### Tried solutions

> Add the following dependencies to the pom file

```
<!--防止报错no method 'getPersistenceUtil'. Assuming JPA 1 environment.-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

#### logs

[image]

[image]

> I want to know how to troubleshoot this problem

Repo:https://github.com/sukai-cheng/foodie-dev

Comment: Change your root log level to something lower like WARN or ERROR

Comment: I want to figure out what does it mean instead of ignoring

Comment: what version of spring boot you are using?

Comment: thank for you response, my version of spring boot is 2.1.5

Comment: are you also using spring cloud?

Comment: nope, it's just a maven project

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239399/discussion-between--and-mystery).